# How can I get my response from my POST request retrofit call to my Fragment

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, retrofit, viewmodel

My goal is to capture or get a **response** from my viewModel into my signUp-Fragment when I click the signUp-Button and navigate to verification-Fragment **if response.status is true**.

When I click on my signUp button in my signUpFragment, a POST request retrofit call is made and **a response** is received like this :

```
UserResponse(message=Sign up successful. A verfication code has been sent to your email address, payload=UserPayload(country=Nigeria, createdAt=2020-04-10T10:55:06.220Z, email=osehiproductengineer@gmail.com, id=5e90508a455f70002f19b42e, isVerified=false, name=osehiase ehilen, phone=07083372454, updatedAt=2020-04-10T10:55:06.220Z, v=0), status=200, token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1ZTkwNTA4YTQ1NWY3MDAwMmYxOWI0MmUiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODY1MTYxMDYsImV4cCI6MTU4NjYwMjUwNn0.H_JhBQY-3PQ6Kqk7SS0cm8RP_1mzYlD987M66_LT0PU)
```

I saw this response using Log; the response does not get to my signUp-Fragment.

Here is my Repository code below:

```
 class NetworkRepository(): BaseRepository() {

    val userApi = UserAPI()
    val authAPI = AuthAPI()
    val treeAPI = TreeAPI()
    val paymentAPI = PaymentAPI()
    val loginAPI = LoginAPI()

    val TAG = "NETWORK REPOSITORY"

    private val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
    val networkState: LiveData<NetworkState>
        get() = _networkState




    //User
    suspend fun createUser(userBody: UserBody): UserResponse {
        var status = UserResponse()

//        Log.d("SIGNUP_RESPONSE2", "inside status:$status")
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                status = userApi.addUserAsync(userBody).await()

//                Log.d("signup_Response3", "after the call:$status")
            }catch (t: Throwable){
                Log.e(TAG, t.message.toString())
            }
        }
        Log.d("SIGNUP_RESPONSE", "here is the $status")

        return status


    }
}
```

Here is my viewModel code:

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel(){
    private val repository = NetworkRepository()
    private val job = Job()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)




    fun createUser(userBody: UserBody):UserResponse {
        var userPayload: UserResponse = UserResponse()
//        Log.d("USERVIEWMODEL_TOP", "the first response:$userPayload")
            scope.launch {
//            userPayload = repository.createUser(userBody)

                userPayload = repository.createUser(userBody)

//            Log.d("USERVIEWMODELCHCK", "speak now:$userPayload")
        }

//        Log.d("USERVIEWMODEL_RESPONSE", "check this userViewModelRes:$userPayload")
        return userPayload
    }
}
```

Here is my SignUp-Fragment Code:

```
class SignUpFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: UserViewModel
    private lateinit var userBody: UserBody
     var captureStatus:UserResponse = UserResponse()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)




        signup_submit_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val response = sendUser()

//        Log.d("SIGNUP_FRAGMENTRES", "where is this response:$response")
            if (response.status == 200) {
                Log.d("SIGNUP_FRAGMENT", "wat is here:${response}")
                saveUserInfo(response)
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_signUpFragment_to_verificationFragment)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this.context,
                    "${response.status}, ${response.message}",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }

        }

        signup_have_an_account.paintFlags = Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG

        signup_have_an_account.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_signUpFragment_to_loginFragment)
        }

        signup_back_btn.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }
    }

    private fun sendUser(): UserResponse {
        var userBody: UserBody? = null
        //verification
        when {
            signup_email_input.editText!!.text.isEmpty() -> {
                signup_email_input.editText!!.error = "Email cannot be empty"
            }
            signup_phone_input.editText!!.text.isEmpty() -> {
                signup_phone_input.editText!!.error = "Phone cannot be empty"
            }
            signup_country_input.editText!!.text.isEmpty() -> {
                signup_country_input.editText!!.error = "Country cannot be empty"
            }
            signup_password_input.editText!!.text.isEmpty() -> {
                signup_password_input.editText!!.error = "Password cannot be empty"
            }
            signup_password_input.editText!!.text.length < 6 -> {
                signup_password_input.editText!!.error = "Password cannot be less than 6 characters"
            }
            signup_name_input.editText!!.text.isEmpty() -> {
                signup_name_input.editText!!.error = "Name cannot be empty"
            }
            else -> {
                val email = signup_email_input.editText!!.text.toString()
                val country = signup_country_input.editText!!.text.toString()
                val name = signup_name_input.editText!!.text.toString()
                val password = signup_password_input.editText!!.text.toString()
                val phone = signup_phone_input.editText!!.text.toString()
                userBody = UserBody(country, email, false, name, password, phone)
            }
        }




//        Log.d("USER REG", userBody.toString())



        return viewModel.createUser(userBody!!)


    }

    private fun saveUserInfo(userResponse: UserResponse) {
        this.activity?.let { Preferences.setEmail(it, userResponse.payload!!.email) }
        this.activity?.let { Preferences.saveAuthToken(it, userResponse.token!!) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bad approach to instantiate variable (like: `status`, `userPayload`) with some Dummy Object, and then changing it with response from other method, then returning it via `return` function. You should better instantiate it with null and return the response to calling function via `callback`. Then if you have null you immediately now, something goes wrong.

---

The above approach is source of your problem. Because the `createUser` function is returning DummyObject, not actual object from Retrofit. To fix this, you need to delete `return` function from `createUser` method. And then add callback or higher-order function as second parameter.

Here is example of higher-order function, which is used as callback, when user is created:

**`createUser` in ViewModel**

```
fun createUser(userBody: UserBody, onUserCreated: (UserResponse) -> Unit) {
    //Log.d("USERVIEWMODEL_TOP", "the first response:$userPayload")
    scope.launch {
        //userPayload = repository.createUser(userBody)

        val userPayload: UserResponse = repository.createUser(userBody)
        onUserCreated(userPayload)

        //Log.d("USERVIEWMODELCHCK", "speak now:$userPayload")
    }
}
```

> **Why this way?** Because `scope.launch{...}` is something like closed environment and you have to get somehow `userPayload` from inside curly brackets `scope.launch{ ... }`. In your solution, you are returning `userPayload` from outisde of `scope.launch{}` which knows nothing about what happens inside `{}`

Also modify `createUser` function in your repository:

**`createUser` in repository:**

```
suspend fun createUser(userBody: UserBody): UserResponse {

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val status = userApi.addUserAsync(userBody).await()

            //Will be used as returend value.
            status
        } catch (t: Throwable) {

            //Will be used as returned value - in case of error.
            UserResponse()
        }
    }
}
```

> **Why?** The same reason as above. You were returning status from outside of `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}`. So due to we want to return something from inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` - we need to add return statement just before `withContext`. In this case last line from `try {}` or last line from `catch{}`(in case of error) will be used as return value for `return` statement before `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}`

And now you should be able to receive response in your fragment, by calling `createUser` function this way:

**fragment**

```
viewModel.createUser(userBody) { response ->
    if (response.status == 200) {
        Log.d("SIGNUP_FRAGMENT", "wat is here:${response}")
        saveUserInfo(response)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_signUpFragment_to_verificationFragment)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this.context,
            "${response.status}, ${response.message}",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: please I am having a kotlinNullPointerException @RediOne1 at saveUserInfo method.

Comment: `repository.createUser(userBody)` is working Ok? Is returning correct Response or null?

Comment: I cannot get Log output of repository.createUser(userBody) because the code did not run completely.

Comment: I am having a kotlinNullPointerException in my Repositroy(my Repository code is above), at **return status!!**. I initialize **status** like this: **var status:UserResponse? = null**

Comment: @OsehiaseEhilen I added required modification for your repository. Check updated answer ;-)

Comment: I implemented the pattern in my repository and it's working, thank you for being there.

Answer (score 0):

```
userPayload = repository.createUser(userBody)
```

This line in your ViewModel will execute in background thread and hence is asynchronus, In order to publish "userPayload" object to your fragment, you need to make use of LiveData like this

```
//Define a mutablelivedata property in your ViewModel
public var userPayloadLiveData = MutableLiveData<UserResponse>()
```

From the co-routine inside your ViewModel you need to post your response to the livedata as such

```
userPayload = repository.createUser(userBody)
userPayloadLiveData.postValue(userPayload)
```

From your fragment you need to observe the "userPayloadLiveData" for async changes in value.

```
viewModel.userPayloadLiveData.observe(this, Observer { userResponse ->

    //this code will run after network call and now safe to do UI stuff.
    //userResponse is your response object

})
```

To understand more about how LiveData or MutableLiveData works please refer to androidx docs [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData)